# Fit arbitrary number of elements in a 10-column grid with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Thats my code:

```
<div *ngFor="let minute of state.minutes.specificMinutes.selectedMinutes | keyvalue" class="col-sm-1 checkbox-container">
   <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" (click)="state.minutes.subTab='specificMinutes'"
            class="custom-control-input" id="minute-{{minute.key}}-checkbox"">
     <label class="custom-control-label" for="minute-{{minute.key}}-checkbox">{{minute.key}}</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Because 12 columns fit in a row, I get 12 custom-controls into a row by using the class `col-sm-1`. But I would like to have exactly 10 custom-controls inside that row which I can't figure out how to do because of something like `col-sm-1.2` isn't possible of course. How can I do it?

There are more than 10 items in the array, and the exact number is unknown.

Comment: create your class setting width:10%.

Comment: Just use simply 'col'

Answer (score 4):

You can simply put the `class="col"`, it will equally distribute the space among 10 columns

Comment: But i have more than 10 elements, i would like it to wrap when it reaches 10 elements in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an arbitrary number of items, what you can do is in your component class chunk your array/list into another array of 10 items. And then loop through twice.

Example function in your component class:

```
chunkArray() {
  let minutes = this.state.minutes.specificMinutes.selectedMinutes;
  let chunks = [];
  let chunkSize = 10;
  for (let i = 0, j = minutes.length; i < j; i += chunkSize) {
    chunks.push(minutes.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
  }

  return chunks;
};
```

Then, in your template do two nested `*ngFor`s, something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let minutes of getChunks()" class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let minute of minutes | keyvalue" class="col checkbox-container">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" (click)="state.minutes.subTab='specificMinutes'" class="custom-control-input"
        id="minute-{{minute.key}}-checkbox"">
       <label class=" custom-control-label" for="minute-{{minute.key}}-checkbox">{{minute.key}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first `ngFor` will render a row per chunk. The inner one will render the actual elements.

On the inner one, using `class="col"` will evenly spread items into 10 columns.

The best part is, if your requirement changes to display any other number of items per row, all you have to do is change `chunkSize`.

**Update**

Actually, since you don't know how many items you will have, and they won't necessarily be in multiples of 10, your last chunk may end-up with less than 10 items. In this case, you can either switch your mark up to this:

```
<div *ngFor="let minutes of getChunks()" class="row">
  <div class="offset-sm-1></div>
  <div *ngFor="let minute of minutes | keyvalue" class="col-sm-1 checkbox-container">
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="offset-sm-1></div>
</div>
```

...or in the `getChunks()` function padd the last array with elements to fill up to 10 items. Then in the template you will have to generate "ghost" elements until the end of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty column on either side.

```css
.control {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: deeppink;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <!-- EMPTY -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="control">*</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="control">*</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="control">*</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="control">*</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="control">*</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="control">*</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="control">*</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="control">*</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="control">*</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="control">*</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <!-- EMPTY -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an offset.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1 offset-sm-1">col</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">col</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">col</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">col</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">col</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">col</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">col</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">col</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">col</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">col</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><!-- Last Div Remains Empty --></div>
</div>
```

Or try something custom:

```css
/*  SECTIONS  */

.section {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


/*  COLUMN SETUP  */

.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
}

.col:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}


/*  GROUPING  */

.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.group:after {
  clear: both;
}

.group {
  zoom: 1;
  /* For IE 6/7 */
}


/*  GRID OF TEN  */

.span_10_of_10 {
  width: 100%;
}

.span_9_of_10 {
  width: 90%;
}

.span_8_of_10 {
  width: 80%;
}

.span_7_of_10 {
  width: 70%;
}

.span_6_of_10 {
  width: 60%;
}

.span_5_of_10 {
  width: 50%;
}

.span_4_of_10 {
  width: 40%;
}

.span_3_of_10 {
  width: 30%;
}

.span_2_of_10 {
  width: 20%;
}

.span_1_of_10 {
  width: 10%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .col {
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
  }
  .span_1_of_10,
  .span_2_of_10,
  .span_3_of_10,
  .span_4_of_10,
  .span_5_of_10,
  .span_6_of_10,
  .span_7_of_10,
  .span_8_of_10,
  .span_9_of_10,
  .span_10_of_10 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_10">
    1 of 10
  </div>
</div>
```